# Modify Oracle DB Enum column with more options - Laravel Migration

Tags: laravel, oracle, migration, alter-table, laravel-migrations

I'm looking for a way to add more options to a Enum column of a table in Oracle Database in my Laravel Project.

This is what I have tried so far. but it gives me the following error.

```
public function up()
{
    DB::statement("ALTER TABLE tokens MODIFY COLUMN status ENUM('pending','in_progress','completed','hold','reject') DEFAULT 'pending'");
}
```

This returns the following error.

```
  Error Code    : 905                                                                                                                  
  Error Message : ORA-00905: missing keyword                                                                                           
  Position      : 40                                                                                                                   
  Statement     : ALTER TABLE tokens MODIFY COLUMN status ENUM('pending','in_progress','completed','hold','reject') DEFAULT 'pending'  
  Bindings      : []
```

How to achieve this ?

Comment: enum doesn't exists in oracle DB

Comment: But this column has been initially created as an ENUM column (by the initial developer).

Comment: are you sure that he was using oracle and not mysql?

Comment: Yeah it is an Oracle DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In oracle you can do something like this:

Creating the table:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE TOKENS (
  2  STATUS VARCHAR2(100)
  3  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Adding the constraints and default

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE TOKENS MODIFY
  2  STATUS DEFAULT 'pending';

Table altered.

SQL>
SQL> ALTER TABLE TOKENS
  2  ADD CONSTRAINT TOKEN_STATUS_CHK CHECK ( STATUS IN (
  3  'pending',
  4  'in_progress',
  5  'completed',
  6  'hold',
  7  'reject'
  8  ) );

Table altered.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the table is already created one. I cannot afford to loose any data in the table or column since this is in production.

Comment: Your answer starts after **Adding the constraints and default** -- I have created a table to give proper example. You do not have to create the table again.

Comment: Your answer works like a charm! Thanks a lot! Btw, since I'm running this as a Laravel migration, what to add as the rollback command ?

Answer (score 1):

i think what you what is

```sql
alter table
   tokens
add constraint
   check_constraint
   CHECK
   (status IN
      (
       'pending','in_progress','completed','hold','reject'
      )
   )ENABLE;

-- set default
ALTER TABLE tokens modify status DEFAULT 'pending';
```

Comment: `ALTER TABLE tokens ALTER status SET DEFAULT 'pending';` is incorrect